# Gradle Jetty plugin locking files

Tags: jetty, gradle

Is there a way to fix the file locking issue caused by `jetty` entirely from `gradle`?

Some clarification:
When using the [Gradle Jetty plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html) by running `gradle jettyRun,` jetty causes the static resource files (html, css, js, etc.) to be locked when using Windows.
You can see a description of the problem in [Files locked on Windows](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Files+locked+on+Windows).

The same article also describes how you can fix that. Basically you have to either:

1. Disable the use of file mapped buffer
2. Not use NIO at all.

Both things require to add some jetty specific configuration files to the project, which I do not want to do - the jetty plugin is used only for convenience, and maintaining configuration for it does not feel right.

I do not need NIO for testing on the local machine, so any solution works.

**Edit:**

For now, I picked the option at which you set `useFileMappedBuffer` to `false`. This is how to do it:

1. Specify a path to your `webdefault.xml` like

   ```
   [jettyRun, jettyRunWar,jettyStop]*.with {
       //other configs

       webDefaultXml = file("${project.webAppDir}/WEB-INF/jetty-webdefault.xml")
   }
   ```
2. Get file from the latest 6.1.x distribution of jetty. The plugin seems to support only jetty 6. You can localte it at `jetty-6.1.26\etc\webdefault.xml`. Obviously, you have to place it at the path specified at the previous step.
3. Change the default servlet init parameter `useFileMappedBuffer` to `false`

I will research the option of using embeded jetty insted of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiril answered his own question, many thanks. You should follow Kiril's instructions and this will help you find the appropriate `webdefault.xml`.

To find out what version of Jetty is started by Gradle, execute

```
gradle jettyRun -i
```

And you'll see something like this:

```
...
Tmp directory =  determined at runtime
Web defaults = org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
Web overrides =  none
Webapp directory = C:\dev\my-project\src\main\webapp
Starting jetty 6.1.25 ...
jetty-6.1.25
...
```

It took me a while to find a copy of Jetty 6.1.25 as it is no longer listed on the Jetty download page (not even in the archive section!).

You can then grab the appropriate copy of `webdefault.xml` from here, adjusting the version number as appropriate for your needs:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/6.1.25/org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml

Comment: Thanks for the link to the file. I actually stopped using the gradle-jetty-plugin - for debugging I use tomcat launched from eclipse, or  a jetty embedded in the application code itself.

Answer (score 3):

I found a plugin that seem to be a better alternative:

https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty

#### Positives

- **Does not lock your files** and support [hot deployment](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Hot-deployment.html) (even something Gretty call "[fast reload](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Fast-reload.html)")
- Gretty 1.2.0 uses Jetty 9.2.9.v20150224. Jetty plugin provided by Gradle 2.2.1 uses Jetty 6.1.25.
- same task is used `jettyRun` (or more simply `run`).
- "Press any key to stop the server". Jetty plugin required CTRL+C then Y.
- From what I can tell, the [documentation](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/) seem to be awesome ([Gradle's](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html) not so much)

#### Negatives

- A bit more bloated code to setup the buildscript's classpath dependency or apply plugin directly from URL ([see doc](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.html))
- Gretty crash unless you explicitly `apply plugin: 'war'` (Jetty plugin extends the War plugin)